adverbial phrase with comma
In the following sentence

He didn't read it, not even the abstract.

'not even the abstract' looks like an adverbial phrase used to modify 'read'.
I am confused about the comma, what is the purpose of the comma and if the meaning will be changed if I removed the comma

The sentence would be very odd without some form of punctuation before not.  The phrase is like an afterthought - "He didn't even read the abstract" - and there must be a pause before it.

Note that "the abstract" is not an adverbial, but a direct object of "did not even read".

A simple way to look at the comma is that is separates the contrast that "not" introduces: We accept cash only, not cards or checks.

"Not even the abstract" is what one calls, according to A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language (Quirk et al., 1985), an elliptic clause. It stands for "he did not even read the abstract". As such it is normal to separate it from what is another clause, namely "he didn't read it"; in other words, it is not part of the "flow" in this first clause.
This is the most ideal sort of ellipsis as it satisfies the five criteria below; it is called strict ellipsis (A Comrehensive Grammar of the English Language, Quirk et al., § 12.38).
(a) Precise recoverability: "he didn't read" is found in the text.
(b) Elliptical construction is grammatically defective: "not even the abstract" does not stand on its own.
(c) Insertion of missing words results in a grammatical sentence with the same meaning: "He didn't read it, he didn't read  even the abstract" is correct grammatically.
(d) The missing wordds are textually recoverable: "He didn't read" is in the text.
(e) They are present in the text in exactly the same form.

thank you! it is very advanced and not easy to comprehend

@KaruseTang The basic thing to understand is that "He didn't read it, he didn't read even  the abstract." is grammatically correct (although current usage has the adverb "even" before the verb ("he didn't even read"), and has the same meaning; so you could say that, and in this case, and people might do that sometimes, in order to emphasize what they are saying. This is the justification for speaking of ellipsis, that is elimination of what is repetitive. The rest is several precisions showing to what point the ellipsis is perfect (there are several sorts of ellipses).

I don't understand why some trivial or dubious answers get multiple upvotes, while some quality answers like this are neglected.

@EdwinAshworth I ask myself the same thing and think I know the answer. :)
